# How can I 'save' a custom ribbon?

Tags: excel, menu, vba

I have created several macro's for a specific Excel 2007 workbook that we keep on a SharePoint site. I have also created a custom QAT with a button for each of the macro's that we run. When I save the workbook and check it back in, the next person who opens the workbook cannot see the QAT I created. I have saved all the macro's as modules for that specific workbook in the VB Editor. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See if [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-or-import-a-customized-ribbon-b6c4cf09-d2ac-48e2-8797-82a0982012dc) helps.

Comment: Thanks Scott. However, I did forget to mention that I am working in Excel 2007, so there is no export/import option.

Comment: Okay try [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b259c5e-2b5c-4647-a2e9-8432f6b2dc47/how-do-i-export-my-office-2007-customized-quick-access-toolbar-settings?forum=officesetupdeploylegacy).

Comment: Thanks Scott. That was the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Scott provided a good answer (and I appreciate the effort), I found a link that was more fulfilling of my requirements. Here is the link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg987030(v=office.14).aspx

This allows a menu (buttons and macros) to follow a workbook where you save it or send it. I tested by emailing to a colleague and adding it to our SharePoint site. All items and code worked as required and there was no need to perform any customizations on anyone's Excel application on their PC/Laptop.